# How can I create a frontend/GUI page using animations

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, jquery-animate

I want to create a frontend page with animation effects what can I use to create a page like that which shows animating effects on a scroll or can you please suggest me any theme or template which can I use.
I want to create a page like this https://getbabb.com/

Comment: question is too broad to ask, please create some code and face any issue then put code specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Animate.css` library and the Jquery plugin viewport checker. They are free and can help you to animate elements inside your html page.

Viewport checker (Use it to detect when an element it's visible on the viewport)

https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker

Animate (Use it to animate the elements)

https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Comment: Thanks for your help can you please guide me how can I create an image on scroll like you see in this link https://getbabb.com/ when you scroll down some effects is creating image step by step it looks like lines are drawn and then image completes, I hope you uderstand my question.

Comment: It's not difficult, read the documentations provided in the two links and you will figure out how to do the animations, You only need a basic knowledge of Html, css and javascript.